# How to set URl in ADF application....?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have only one page in adf application, the page is called result.jspx. My requirement is - the url needs to be invoked  like http://example.com/ADF_View_Test-ViewController-context-root/faces/result.jspx but when I create ear and deploy it in the weblogic server it is displaying like http://example.com/ADF_View_Test-ViewController-context-root in the url. I am unable to get faces and jspx page. please let me know how to add in the url.

Regards
Santosh

Comment: What JDeveloper version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of your EAR archive, see if result.jspx is part of it. 
If is not, try to recreate deployment profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can always stick an index.html file at the root that does a redirect to where you need it to go.
For example - https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/shorter_url_for_your_adf